# Got 'Exit 255' when using nohup command

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-server, nohup

I'm using the `nohup` command to execute a php file in my Linux Server, previously this command ran smoothly and I have been using it for years, but lately (until now) I've been getting an `Exit 255` after running it. The php script is fine (there is no error).

Here is the command I ran:

> `nohup php /usr/lib/backhandler/backprc.php > backprc.log &`

Here is the reply after ran that command above:

> ```
> root@mine:/# nohup php /usr/lib/backhandler/backprc.php > backprc.log &
> [1] 159713
> root@mine:/# nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
> [1]+  Exit 255                nohup php /usr/lib/backhandler/backprc.php > backprc.log
> ```

Has anyone experienced this too and managed to solve it?
Any input suggestions will help me, thank you guys.

Comment: This means the PHP script failed. The reason should be in the log file.

Comment: do you mean php-fpm logs?

Comment: I have checked the backprc.log, but it's blank

Comment: Check php's error log.

Comment: Usually I will specify the full path of php interpreter and full path of php script (and full path of log : output)

Comment: The problem was solved after I set the default php version down to php 7.4 (previously updated to php 8 by accident after installed the mongoDB library with composer), thank you